# Best way to make "fill the gaps" quiz?

Tags: android

I've used three TextViews. one for "-", second for the empty field and the third for the rest of the sentence.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvS2a.png)

but the problem is that, this is quite buggy and when I add more text to the last TextView (sentence TextView) the text wraps to the bottom of the last TextView instead of the first TextView. Help Please ):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKQR5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one TextView and at runtime set text of it like below:

```
myTextView.setText("-"+"  " + your text);
```

That is all thing you need.

Comment: Thanks **Masoud**,
 but that's not possible because I'm using drag and drop to move another TextView and put it on the Empty TextView which will change it's content. so the empty field should be one TextView.

Comment: At first do my solution and when user drag an answer and drop it on your textView, you could set that text like this: myTextView.setText("-"+correctAnswer + your text);

Comment: @ChavinKwas please add upVote if my answer is useful for you. Thanks.